# Unable to disconnect from iPhone Personal Hotspot

Tags: macos, tethering

I can connect to my iPhone hotspot through Wi-Fi on my MacBook Air, but when I then click **"Disconnect from my iPhone"** in the **Wi-Fi** menu, nothing happens.

The only method I could use disconnect is to disable Personal Hotspot on the iPhone itself.

Disconnecting on my MacBook used to work prior to upgrading to OS X 10.11, El Capitan. Any idea of a fix?

Comment: I have this same problem, although I'm not sure how to fix it beside disconnecting the hotspot from the source. (i.e. iphone,etc.)

Comment: Hmm - sounds like a temporary block. Is this reproducible after you reboot your Mac?

Comment: Actually, this did not help on the long term. I ended up turning off wifi on my mac for a while when I want to disconnect.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

My solution is to "Turn Wi-Fi off" and the enable it again, on the MacBook. Kinda hassle but it solved my issue.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  We like answers to be more than just a single line.  Ideally, you want to explain why your answer is *right."  It also helps to provide links, citations, and/or screen shots.  Please review our help section [How to Answer](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) on writing good answers to questions

Comment: following this answer clearly resolves the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I solved my problem following bmike's instructions: I rebooted my computer!

Comment: Actually, this did not really solve the problem. So I always turn off wifi for a while on my mac. So far I have not found a better solution